Expo SDK 51 expo-camera isHighlightingEnabled
I am using Expo SDK 51 with React Native and Expo Go on iOS 17.5.1.
I want to use expo-camera to scan QR Codes.
The scanning works well, but the "highlight" doesn't appear around the QR Code when the camera is on.
According to the documentation, I need to use launchScanner() and isHighlightingEnabled (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#scanningoptions), but I'm having trouble implementing it and can't find any concrete examples of its usage.
Thanks for your help.
Here is my code:
import { View, Modal } from "react-native";
import { CameraView } from "expo-camera";
import { IconButton } from "react-native-paper";
import { styles } from "./CameraModal.style";

const CameraModal: React.FC<CameraModalProps> = ({
  visible,
  onClose,
  onScan,
}) => (
  <Modal visible={visible} onRequestClose={onClose} animationType="slide">
    <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
      <CameraView
        onBarcodeScanned={onScan}
        barcodeScannerSettings={{ barcodeTypes: ["qr"] }}
      />
      <View style={styles.cameraActions}>
        <IconButton
          icon="close"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#f44336",
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            borderRadius: 100,
          }}
          onPress={onClose}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  </Modal>
);

export default CameraModal;


